I can't connect to socket io with python
I'm trying to connect to a socket io link that returns some results in a web page. The link is: https://s.x13.bet:2053/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P4bEWAn&sid=s5Walx7F2aBWJDTIADXA
But when I try to connect to it in python it does not return nothing to me. (on the website we can see the preview of the results, and actually we have some data in there)
I tried to connect with the following code and it just returns to me "Connected.", but not the message:
import socketio

url = "https://s.x13.bet:2053"

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected.")

@sio.on('message')
def on_message(data):
    print("Message received: ", data)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected.")

sio.connect(url, transports=['polling'], headers={'EIO': '4', 'transport': 'polling', 't': 'P4bEWAn', 'sid': 's5Walx7F2aBWJDTIADXA'})

sio.wait()

